# Using DateSerial function with loop and If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that will hide all past dates and the blank rows in a year long database. The issue with the code below is that the code sees the dates at math problems to solve, i.e `? 1/1/2016 < 1/14/2016 = false` because of division. I had a suggestion to use the DateSerial function but I am not sure how to use it within a loop or the if statement.

Code As is:

```
 Sub Hide_Dates()
 Dim This_Year As Range
 Dim CD As Date
 Dim SD As Date

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 Set This_Year = Range("A5:A3000")
 This_Year.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 i = 5
'CD = Format(Date, "dddd, mmmm dd,yyyy")
 CD = Date

 Do Until Cells(i, 1) = CD

 SD = Cells(i, 1).Value
 Debug.Print i
 Debug.Print SD
 Debug.Print CD
 If SD < CD Or SD = "" Then
     Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If

 i = i + 1
 Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 End Sub
```

Code with DateSerial attempt:

```
  Sub Hide_Dates()
  Dim This_Year As Range
  Dim CD As Date
  Dim SD As Date

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Set This_Year = Range("A5:A3000")
  This_Year.EntireRow.Hidden = False

 'Starts rows down
  i = 5

 'Current date
 'CD = Format(Date, "dddd, mmmm dd,yyyy")
 CD = DateSerial(Today.Year, Today.Month, Today.Day)

 Do Until Cells(i, 1) = CD

'SD = Selected Date in the loop
 SD = Cells(i, 1).Value 'Not sure how to DateSerial this!!!!
 Debug.Print i
 Debug.Print SD
 Debug.Print CD
 'Hides past days
 If SD < CD Or SD = "" Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If

 i = i + 1
 Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem - i.e. what is happening?

Comment: in column A5:A30000 I have dates from 1/1/2016-12/31/2016, I want to hide all past days. The issue is that when it loops thru each  row to see if its todays date its only hiding random days. Because it sees the dates as math problems therefore its not comparing the days it is compare solved math problems. Some one told me to use the dateserial function but I don't know how to use it in a loop with the i or in the if statement. That is what is the problem and what is happening. If you type `1/1/2016 < 1/14/2016` you get false because its solving 1/14 then that divided by 2016.

Comment: "Because it sees the dates as math problems". No it doesn't. It either sees them as dates or as text that looks like a date. Since your first code uses a date variable (`SD`) and you haven't mentioned any errors, any strings are being converted to dates anyway. Perhaps some of the dates have time parts too? Also your code will stop the first time it finds a cell with today's date - is your data sorted?

Comment: I just tested your first piece of code. I changed `Or SD = ""` to `Or IsNull(SD)` and it worked perfectly. My dates were also sorted in chronological order as well.

Comment: I thought it was dividing the numbers because if you put ? 1/1/2016 into the Immediate window it gives 4.96031746031746E-04. @ Scott Holtzman: Worked! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need more than one try at this: it's a problem that you'll solve by eliminating one wrong answer after another.

First up, have a closer look at '.Value' - it's not what you think it is: the logic is to evaluate the contents of the range, taking account of any formatting, including any date formatting.

You might do better with the '.Value2' property of the cell:

`SD = Cells(i, 1).Value2`

The point about '.Value2' is that the underlying numeric data in the cell comes back - not an evaluation of the formatted text - and you sidestep the problem with date serials (or numbers, or expressions containing division '/', or text that looks like formatted dates), which Excel automatically displays with a date format in the cell.

Excel often gets that wrong: are you sure you know what day it is on "07/06/2016" ? If you work with data from more than one country, I can assure you that Excel doesn't. (Also: that luxury car with a price tag of £39,995 probably has nothing to do with your nephew's birthday on July 1st 2009).

Secondly, try `SD = Cells(i, 1).Value2` with a date conversion:

`SD = CVDATE(Cells(i, 1).Value2`

Thirdly, pull out the sledgehammer: select the range receiving your raw data, right-click your way to 'Format Cell...', and apply the category 'Text' - then reimport your raw data.

You need to do that import again: who knows what automatic formatting did to your data?

You can now see what's in there: do you have numeric values? Numbers like 42383 represent dates; numbers like  42383.5987615741  represent date-and-time. Feed 'em straight into `SD = CVDATE(Cells(i, 1)` and run your date comparison. You may get a type conversion error - if so, the strings need conversion to numbers before they are fed into CvDate():

`SD = CVDATE(CDbl(Cells(i, 1))`

Like I said: one wrong answer after another.

If the raw data is text, take a closer look at it: is it consistently formatted? You can feed "01-Jan-2016" straight into CVDate(), but "Thursday 14 January 2016" might be harder: you'll need fairly complex string handling for that. But it's more likely that you'll get dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy and another problem:

Can you check what's in "06/07/2015" and "07/06/2015"? It might be June, it might be July...

...Maybe CVDate() is being a bit too 'helpful' with that.

So the 'Davy Crocket Sledgehammer' is to receive your data in a text-formatted range, and specify how it should be read:

`Dim strDate As String

Dim strDay  As String

Dim strMon  As String

Dim strYear As String`

```
strDate = Cells(i, 1).Text
strDay  = Mid(strDate, 1, 2)
strMon  = Mid(strDate, 4, 2)
strYear = Mid(strDate, 7, 4)
```

...And feed that into a DateSerial() to get your date.

If you've got inconsistent date formatting, your problems are a lot harder: you'll need some error-checking to verify that any given cell can be read as a date at all, and the `IsDate()` function might not be as reliable as you'd hoped. However, there is a way to deal with strings like "24/8/2015" and "1/9/2015" and "14/10/15": use the `VBA.Strings.Split()` function. However, I'll leave that to you.

Also: can you tell that Excel developers get to deal with horrible data?